# What does Tensor representation in null co-ordinates mean?

Tags: energy-conservation, coordinate-systems, field-theory, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider the energy-momentum tensor in quantum field theory for a massless scalar field $\phi$;
$$T_{\alpha \beta} = \phi_{, \alpha} \phi_{, \beta} - \frac{1}{2} \eta_{\alpha \beta} \eta^{\lambda \delta} \phi_{, \lambda} \phi_{, \delta}.$$

For introductory purposes, further simplifcation usually reduces this to $1 + 1$ spacetime dimensions, and in Cartesian co-ordinates the Hamiltonian density is identified as;
$$T_{00} = T_{tt} = \frac{1}{2}[(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t})^2 + (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})^2].$$

In some scenarios, it is useful to use the null co-ordinate prescription instead, $u = t - x \,\ v = t + x$, which means a transformation;
$$T_{tt} = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u})^2 + (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v})^2.$$

However, this is not the correct method to transform tensors. If the correct rule is applied, the energy-momentum tensor in null representation, the $T_{00}$ becomes $(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u})^2$. My understanding is that this formalisation allows the tensor to remain linear in all of its operations when retrieving the conservation of energy and linear momentum in null co-ordinates, however, I do not know the exact mathematical way of expressing this, and what particular meaning $T_{uu}$ has by itself. For example, the vacuum expectation value of the energy is;

$$\int_{u \ \text{min}}^{u \ \text{max}} \langle 0|T_{uu}|0\rangle du$$

but I can't see how this is true because $T_{uu}$ is no longer the energy density.

So to summarise, what does Tensor representation in null co-ordinates mean, and what happens to the energy density in particular?